# Creating a line break using Gboard on Signal and other apps

Tags: applications, gboard

I want to be able to create a line break while using Gboard on Google Pixel 3X.  This will allow me to start a new paragraph while using Signal or another app.

Any ideas here?

Comment: I don't think that this has something to do with the used keyboard. Signal and other messenger apps simply have configured that the return key sends the message. Therefore I would assume that the messenger app itself has to support entering line breaks.

Comment: Some good virtual keyboard apps have an option where you can specify whether enter will send a message or insert a line break.  I don't use Gboard, so I don't know if it is one of those good apps, but you may want to look at its settings to check.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto Signal -> Settings -> Chats
2. Disable "Enter key sends"